# SQLite not pulling data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get data pulled from a SQLite file, i have created many view based applications with only one view to test this code and it runs perfect every time.

But some reason when there is more than one view it does not run all the way through or give out any errors here is the code:

**TorD_Questions.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <sqlite3.h>

@interface TorD_Questions : UIViewController 
{

    sqlite3         *database;

}

- (void) MakeDBCopy;
- (void) GetQuestion;


@end
```

**TorD_Questions.m**

```
#import "I_Dare_YouViewController.h"
#import "About_Page.h"
#import "Settings_Page.h"
#import "Game_Info.h"
#import "Game_TDoR.h"
#import "Settings_Menu.h"
#import "TorD_Questions.h"


@implementation TorD_Questions

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self MakeDBCopy];
    [self GetQuestion];
}

NSString *fileName = @"Questions.sqlite";


- (void) MakeDBCopy
{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) 
    {
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) 
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (void) GetQuestion
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        const char *sql = "select * from Truth";

        sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSString *TheID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
                NSString *TheQuestion = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 1)];
                NSLog(@"ID: %@ Question: %@", TheID, TheQuestion);
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
    }
}

@end
```

If anyone knows of a problem with sqlite and more than one view as this is the only thing i can think of that is different in this over the times i have tested it with only one view.

Thank you in advance.
Eli

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, i fixed it by renaming the SQlite Database.